# how to write a xpath to find tag inside is only <refint> not other tags

Tags: xml, xpath

```
INPUT

<TABLE>
    <THEAD>
    <ROW id="rh">
    <CELL rowmerged="F"  rowspan="1" >
        <Para ><refint>REFINT1</refint>A</Para>
    </CELL>
        <CELL rowmerged="F"  rowspan="1" >
            <Para >B<refint>REFINT2</refint></Para>
        </CELL>
        <CELL rowmerged="F"  rowspan="1" >
            <Para >C<notrefint>REFINT1</notrefint></Para>
        </CELL>
        <CELL rowmerged="F"  rowspan="1" >
            <Para >D</Para>
        </CELL>
        <CELL rowmerged="F"  rowspan="1" >
            <Para >F</Para>
        </CELL>
    </ROW>


</THEAD>
<TBODY editable="T">
    <ROW id="r1">
        <CELL rowmerged="T"  rowspan="2" >
            <Para >11</Para>
        </CELL>
        <CELL rowmerged="T"  rowspan="2" >
            <Para >12</Para>
        </CELL>
        <CELL rowmerged="F"  rowspan="1" >
            <Para >13</Para>
        </CELL>
        <CELL rowmerged="F"  rowspan="1" >
            <Para >14</Para>
        </CELL>
        <CELL rowmerged="T"  rowspan="2" >
            <Para >15</Para>
        </CELL>
    </ROW>

    <ROW id="r2">
        <CELL rowmerged="T"  rowspan="2" >
            <Para ></Para>
        </CELL>
        <CELL rowmerged="T"  rowspan="2" >
            <Para ></Para>
        </CELL>
        <CELL rowmerged="F"  rowspan="1" >
            <Para >23</Para>
        </CELL>
        <CELL rowmerged="F"  rowspan="1" >
            <Para >24</Para>
        </CELL>
        <CELL rowmerged="T"  rowspan="2" >
            <Para ></Para>
        </CELL>
    </ROW>

    <ROW id="r3">
        <CELL rowmerged="T"  rowspan="2" >
            <Para ></Para>
        </CELL>
        <CELL rowmerged="T"  rowspan="2" >
            <Para ></Para>
        </CELL>
        <CELL rowmerged="F"  rowspan="1" >
            <Para >33</Para>
        </CELL>
        <CELL rowmerged="F"  rowspan="1" >
            <Para >34</Para>
        </CELL>
        <CELL rowmerged="T"  rowspan="2" >
            <Para ></Para>
        </CELL>
    </ROW>

    <ROW id="r4">
        <CELL rowmerged="F"  rowspan="1" >
            <Para >41</Para>
        </CELL>
        <CELL rowmerged="F"  rowspan="1" >
            <Para >42</Para>
        </CELL>
        <CELL rowmerged="F"  rowspan="1" >
            <Para >43</Para>
        </CELL>
        <CELL rowmerged="F"  rowspan="1" >
            <Para >44</Para>
        </CELL>
        <CELL rowmerged="T"  rowspan="1" >
            <Para >45</Para>
        </CELL>
    </ROW>
    </TBODY>
</TABLE>
```

I am new to xpath and don't know how to write a condition in xpath to fetch the inner tag in THEAD is only `<refint></refint>` not an yother tags.
how to write a xpath to find tag inside is only `<refint>` not other tags

I need an solution to fetch whether the inner tag in THEAD is `<refint>`

Comment: I'm afraid your English doesn't really make sense here. Could you please show us an example of which elements you are trying to select here and what the reasoning behind it is?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this?

```
/TABLE/THEAD/ROW/CELL[1]/Para/refint
```

Or this?

```
/TABLE/THEAD/.//refint
```

question is a bit vague I think